# How to show Product Custom dropdown Attriute without filtering all attributes in vuestorefront?

Tags: magento2.4, vue-storefront, vue

I Have a brand Attribute in Magento 2.4.2 and and i am getting is value like 5 but i want to show its label like puma. this is showing in product details but i want to show below sku in vue-storefront only brand not other attributes. any idea how can i achive this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunatly i found a simple solution for this but  for i now i changes in core files but soon i will get solution without changes in core files and much proper solution.

for this now i have create a file SingleProductAttribute.ts exactly like ProductAttribute.ts in vue-storefront/core/modules/catalog/components/SingleProductAttribute.ts

```
export const SingleProductAttribute = {
  name: 'SingleProductAttribute',
  props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    attribute: {
      type: null,
      required: true
    },
    emptyPlaceholder: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    label () {
      let labels = [];
      labels.push((this.attribute && this.attribute.default_frontend_label) ?
        this.attribute.default_frontend_label :
        ((this.attribute && this.attribute.default_frontend_label) ? this.attribute.default_frontend_label : ''));
      //return labels.join(', ');
      return ((this.attribute && this.attribute.default_frontend_label) ?
        this.attribute.default_frontend_label :
        ((this.attribute && this.attribute.default_frontend_label) ? this.attribute.default_frontend_label : ''));
    },
    value () {
      console.log(this.attribute);
      let parsedValues = this.attribute.options;
      let parsedVal = this.product[this.attribute.attribute_code];
      if (!parsedValues) {
        return this.emptyPlaceholder
      } else if (this.attribute.frontend_input !== 'multiselect' && this.attribute.frontend_input !== 'select') {
        return parsedValues.toString()
      } else {
        parsedValues = typeof parsedValues === 'string' ? parsedValues.split(',') : parsedValues

        let results = []
        let option = this.attribute.options.find(av => {
              /* eslint eqeqeq: "off" */
              return av.value == parsedVal
        })
        if (option) {
          console.log('option label =>',option.label);
            results.push(option.label)
        } else {
          console.log('option value =>',option.label);
           results.push(parsedVal)
        }
        return results.join(', ')
  }
}
  }
}
```

and then create a component name CsAttribute.vue
in vue-storefront/src/themes/fashion/components/core/CsAttribute.vue
it is also quite similar to ProductAttribute.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
  <span>{{ label }} </span>
  <span class="weight-700">{{ value|htmlDecode }}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { SingleProductAttribute } from '@vue-storefront/core/modules/catalog/components/SingleProductAttribute.ts'

export default {
  mixins: [SingleProductAttribute]
}
</script>
```

and last this some changes in Product.vue

```
getCsAttributes () {
      return this.attributesByCode['cs_attribute']
    },
```

and

i know this is not exact but it is quite similer answer.